# How to set email to be expired?

Tags: php

I want to know about PHPMailer function. Is it possible to make email link to be expired?

I have case like this, when user click link that send from mobile apps or other to set their new password. After they created new password, then they will login again with the new password. what if click the link again, it will repeating the process again. I want to make the link will be expired if they are already create new password.

CMIIW

Comment: Too broad... Please search for a tutorial on this topic in google.

Comment: Log when its clicked the first time

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard yes it is in very details for techees to understand my need, please share, please suggest if some shortening way in your mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expiring the link has *absolutely nothing* to do with PHPMailer.

You are, presumably, storing a token in a database and sending that token to the user (embedded in a URL).

When that token is passed to the *reset password* page, you allow the password to be reset.

You can expire the token in any way you like. The simplest way to do that when the new password is to run a DELETE query over the row with the token in at the time you set the new password.

Comment: @Quesntin so when user create new password i also delete token that i send from the first time, so when they use the token it will not process. thank you, very hopefull answer